# Writing timestamps to database - gocql vs cqlsh

Tags: go, cassandra, cql, gocql

Desired format to write time stamp, in cassandra database:

```
  2021-01-17 21:51:46.195
```

Using cqlsh syntax for insert query:

1. am able to write the above format using `toTimeStamp(toDate(now()))`
2. Using cqlsh, am unable to write the above format using `toUnixTimestamp(now())`. `toUnixTimestamp(now())` writes the format `2021-01-17 21:51:46.195000+0000`.

---

```
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"

    timestamp := "2021-01-17T21:51:46.195Z"
    createdDate, err := time.Parse(layout, timestamp)
    insertQueryString = "INSERT INTO mytable(created_date) " + "VALUES (?)"
```

`gocql.Session.Query(insertQueryString, createdDate).Exec()` code also writes `createdDate` into database similar to the format that cqlsh's `toUnixTimestamp(now())` does, which is `2021-01-17 21:51:46.195000+0000` as shown below:

[image]

---

JimB already explained: "Again, time.Time has no format. You can format it as a string if you want, which is explained in numerous other answers."

But,

How to make `gocql.Session.Query(insertQueryString, createdDate).Exec()`  write `createdDate`  as `2021-01-17 21:51:46.195`? Because `cqlsh` is **able to write** this desired format using `toTimeStamp(toDate(now()))`

Comment: You've been a regular on SO for quite some time now. You should know by now to [not paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860).

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra doesn't keep timestamp as string, it's stored inside dataabase as `long` number with milliseconds precision 8 bytes long (see [protocol specification](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec#L929)).  Conversion of the number into the string is the responsibility of the client program, and `cqlsh` is the python-based client shipped with Cassandra.  And cqlsh has the configuration option that controls how the timestamp will be rendered - this is the `datetimeformat` option of the [cqlshrc configuration file](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshCqlshrc.html#ChangingtheCQLshelldisplay) that you can customize to print dates as needed.